# Appears in the NgModule.imports of ProductsModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I have multi module angular project and also i have created a my own  **ImagegalleryComponent** to use across multiple modules.I have tried to import it everywhere it gives me different issues every time .

finally i try to import it in app.module but still it gives me same issue

here is my app.module with  ImagegalleryComponent.

```
    @NgModule({
   imports: [
   
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAO7Mg2Cs1qzo_3jkKkZAKY6jtwIlm41-I'
    }),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    SharedModule,
    SortablejsModule.forRoot({ animation: 150 }),
    MatCarouselModule.forRoot(),
   
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PagesComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    TopMenuComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    SidenavMenuComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    OptionsComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ImagegalleryComponent, 
  ], 
  providers: [
    AppSettings,
    AppService,   
    { provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer },
    { provide: MAT_MENU_SCROLL_STRATEGY, useFactory: menuScrollStrategy, deps: [Overlay] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents :[productlistresolver]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is my products Module

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    ProductsComponent, 
    ProductComponent, 
    ProductZoomComponent ,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SwiperModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    SharedModule,
    PipesModule,
    ImagegalleryComponent, 
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    ProductZoomComponent 
  ],
  providers : [productResolver ,getProdoductInfoResolver]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

this is my admin module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    UserMenuComponent,
    FullScreenComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule,
    InputFileModule.forRoot(config),
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

can someone please let me know how can i import this imagegallery components for other sub modules please.I figured im doing something wrong here..!

Error Message

```
Error: src/app/imagegallery/imagegallery.component.ts:14:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of ProductsModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

14 export class ImagegalleryComponent implements OnInit {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

************************** Update *************************

according to the comments. i followed approach 1

Newly Created ImageGallery.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ImagegalleryComponent } from "./imagegallery.component";

@NgModule({

    declarations: [
      ImagegalleryComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
    ],
    providers : []
  })
  export class ImagegalleryModule { }
```

Then i imported products.module.ts like below

```
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    MatCarouselModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    SwiperModule,
    InputFileModule,
    SortablejsModule,
    ImagegalleryModule
  ],
  providers :[productlistresolver ,productdetailresolver]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

New error messge

```
Error: src/app/pages/products/product/product.component.html:8:31 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'imagelist' since it isn't a known property of 'app-imagegallery'.
1. If 'app-imagegallery' is an Angular component and it has 'imagelist' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-imagegallery' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8             <app-imagegallery [imagelist]="product.images"></app-imagegallery>
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/products/product/product.component.ts:13:16
    13   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Updated with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. For your personalized module to work, it needs to export the component you wish to make available in other parts of your app. Otherwise, even importing `ImagegalleryModule` in your other modules won't work, because it's not making anything inside of it "visible" to the exterior:

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ImagegalleryComponent } from "./imagegallery.component";

@NgModule({

    declarations: [
      ImagegalleryComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
    ],
    // You need to add these lines:
    // ============================
    exports: [
      ImagegalleryComponent
    ]
    // ============================
    providers : []
  })
  export class ImagegalleryModule { }
```

And then, you add `ImagegalleryModule` to the `imports` array of `AppModule` or whichever Module you wish.

Comment: pavan bring me so far and he was very helpful but for other people reference i'd mark this as the correct answer.Thank you both

Answer (score 2):

In Angular v14 or before, you need to define component in NgModule then import that module if you want the component in other modules. You can do this 2 ways

1. Define separate module for `ImagegalleryComponent`

**ImagegalleryModule.ts**

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    ImagegalleryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
     ........
  ],
  providers : [........]
})
export class ImagegalleryModule { }
```

In this way, you can import this module anywhere

2. Or add `ImagegalleryComponent`  to existing module

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    ProductsComponent, 
    ProductComponent, 
    ProductZoomComponent ,
    ImagegalleryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SwiperModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    SharedModule,
    PipesModule,
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    ProductZoomComponent 
  ],
  providers : [productResolver ,getProdoductInfoResolver]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

Every time you need **ImagegalleryComponent**, just import **ProductsModule**

---

FYI: But if you are using Angular 14, you can define the component as standalone and import it anywhere you like. See this demo https://angular-ivy-9rbeic.stackblitz.io for clarification

Comment: Error: src/app/pages/products/product/product.component.html:8:31 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'imagelist' since it isn't a known property of 'app-imagegallery'.
1. If 'app-imagegallery' is an Angular component and it has 'imagelist' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-imagegallery' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the

Comment: '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8             <app-imagegallery [imagelist]="product.images"></app-imagegallery>
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/products/product/product.component.ts:13:16
    13   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.

Comment: If you followed approach 1, Import `ImagegalleryModule` onto `ProductsModule`. Could you create StackBlitz example?

Comment: sorry i never worked in this platform kind of confusing how can i create exact project